# Fire rated cap for recessed lighting can

Tags: lighting, led

I am in the process of installing 6inch retrofit LED recessed lighting in the first and second floor.

This is a remodel.

I intend to use airtight IC rated cans for the same.
For the first floor there is no insulation
The second floor has insulation and roof access through attic.

The inspector with the township wants to know what type of fire rated cap I will be using.

I then started researching about the installation of fire caps which requires me cut into the sheet rock and close spackle  and paint it again. There is obviously more time/cost involved.

Question is are the caps really required by code?

I tried looking up NEC code for recessed lighting with fire caps but couldn't find much

Any guidance appreciated. If anyone can point me to related documentation of the fire cap requirements for LED recessed lighting that will be great.

Thanks

Comment: The 2nd floor cans must be IC rated, IC stands for Insulation Contact.

Comment: @Tyson Thank you. I intend to get the IC cans. But my question is regarding the requirement of fire caps on those cans. Are fire rated caps required by code for LED lighting ? For the second floor it us not a hassle as there is roof access via attic but it is a hassle for the first floor. The inspector seems to suggest it is mandatory for both floor.

Comment: I guess I should have typed a few more words, but with it rated cans you shouldn't need the firecap. Only time I've seen those used was once when an architect spec'd a non-IC can and we couldn't by the same can in IC.

Comment: That makes sense. That is why I am trying to find some documentation so I can talk to the township inspector.

Comment: There isn't much on the piece of paper but go buy an IC rated can and take the instructions which clearly indicate it's rated for direct insulation contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much wrangling, the inspector provided a suggestion that worked.

He indicated that the below fire hats can be folded and inserted through the 6 inch hole.

http://www.tenmatusa.com/insulation-protection-covers/ff130e-recessed-light-draft-stop-cover/

Then get the can in place and we are all set.

I now have approval and final inspection done